# RingCT 3.0 in Monero

Tags: ringct

Is there a plan to transfer Monero to RingCT 3.0 (https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/508.pdf)?
Is there any (test) implementation of RingCT 3.0 in computer code or at least parts of it?
The authors' arguments seem to me quite convincing.

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a plan to transfer Monero to RingCT 3.0?

The Monero Research Lab are looking into RingCT 3, Lelantus *and* Omniring as I recall.

There would be no migration until a careful evaluation was complete, followed by an implementation developed and audited.

> Is there any (test) implementation of RingCT 3.0 in computer code or at least parts of it?

Only some MRL [test code](https://github.com/SarangNoether/skunkworks/tree/rct3) to my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks @jtgrassie for the answer. Are there any direct comparisons of these technologies? That would be very interesting.
Omniring, by the way, is also a very fascinating technology. Is there any (test) implementation of Omniring in computer code or at least parts of it?